# Must all inner-product preserving maps be linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, isometry

Must all inner-product preserving maps be linear?

Answer (score 2):

For all $x,y,z,\mu,\nu$, you want $\langle f(x),f(\lambda y+\mu z)\rangle=\langle x,\lambda y\rangle+\langle x,\mu z\rangle$ and, so, for all $x'\in\operatorname{im} f$ the map $\langle x',f(\bullet)\rangle$ is linear.

Assume as a contradiction that there are $x,y,\mu,\nu$ such that $w=f(\lambda x+\mu y)-\lambda f(x)-\mu f(y)\ne 0$. Then, \begin{align}0<&\langle w,w\rangle=\langle w,f(\lambda x+\mu y)\rangle-\lambda\langle w,f( x)\rangle-\mu\langle w,f( y)\rangle=\text{(linearity)}\\=&\langle w, f(\lambda x+\mu y-\lambda x-\mu y)\rangle=\langle w,f(0)\rangle=0\end{align}

Absurd.

Comment: thank you. so it means that if domain and codomain have same dimension, then preserving inner product map between them must be linear map. I got it

Comment: @user330235 The requirement on the dimension is not particularly relevant in this. The important ingredient is that $\langle x,x\rangle\ne 0$ for all $x$ or, to scringe for minimality, that there is no vector $u\in\operatorname{im} f$ such that $\langle u,v\rangle=0$ for all $v\in\operatorname{im} f$. All these facts are obvious for the usual positive-definite inner products.